# Is the closure of the span in a Banach space complete?

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces

As indicated by the title os the post, I am interested in the following question

> Is the closure of the linear span in a Banach space again a Banach space?

If it is true, where I could find the reference, and if it is false, is there a counter example? Thanks!

Comment: Any closed set (a span or not) in a complete metric space (e.g. a Banach space) is complete. This is a well-known fact that doesn't really need to be referenced in academic writing. It is quite straightforward to prove, and I suggest trying to prove it yourself. Hint: if $A$ is a closed subset of Banach space $X$, and $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $A$, then it is Cauchy in $X$.

Comment: Ah ok, this is indeed a basic fact. Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries!${}{}$

Answer (score 3):

As Theo Bendit nicely stated in the comments, any closed set (and the closure of any set is indeed a closed set) in a complete metric space is complete. Then Theo showed you a nice hint to prove the proposition that I totally endorse. (Note that it is also true that a complete subset of a metric space is closed).

I just wanted to add a remark about the fact that you can use the sequential characterization of closed sets (the definition Theo used) since you are in a Banach space (hence in a metric space). Having your space to be metrizable is a sufficient (though not necessary (!) ) condition to ensure that a closed set (defined as “the complement is open”) is sequentially closed and viceversa.

Comment: yah thank you so much, 1 upvote!

Comment: Happy to (add some) help :)